# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in <file>

Tags: php, mysql

Please someone tell me where I am wrong? I am getting the following error when I am running the script:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\baljeet2\ViewAllPolicy1.php on line 32

Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor='white'>
<?PHP
include 'config.php';
session_start();

//if ($_SESSION['auth']!='TRUE') {

//header ("Location: ../a_login.php");

//}

?>

<?PHP

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$DB_name);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   else
   {
   echo "";
   }  

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM policydetail1");
echo "pass<br>";

int $num_rows=0;


$num_rows= mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num==0) {
  // Show message
    echo "No record Found";
} else {
  // do your while stuff here

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['CompanyName']." ".$row['PolicyNo']." ".$row['OD']." ".$row['ThirdParty']." ".$row['ServiceTaxRate']." ".$row['TotalAmount']." ".$row['Discount']." ".$row['CommissionRate']." ".$row['Commission']." ".$row['CommissionStatus']." ".$row['Date']."<br>";
}

}

    mysqli_close($con);





     //echo "<div align='center'><div style='background-color:#4682B4; color:white; width:1000px; height:30px; text-align:center; font-family:trebuchet ms;'>Policy Add Succefully!!!</div></div><br> <div align='center'><a href='Add Policy Form.html'>Add more records</a><a href='Add Policy Form.html'> <BR>Back to Main Menu</a></div>";

    ?>
```

I am new to PHP and doing hard to find this error. Code on line 32 is following:

```
int $num_rows=0; //Here I am getting error
```

I also checked the semicolons and syntax but nothing found.

Comment: `int $num_rows = 0;` is _not_ valid PHP.

Comment: Remove the `int` keyword, as PHP variable declarations are not typed as in C/C++/Java.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

Php is dynamic typing language. This means that variables have no type. Is the runtime that known the type in base of the content of a variable.

```
<?php

    $var = 0;     echo gettype($var);  // integer
    $str = 'str'; echo gettype($str);  // string
    $boo = false; echo gettype($boo$); // boolean
```

If you need, you can cast values:

```
<?php

    $integer = '3';              // now is a string
    $number = 2 * (int)$integer; // '3' becomes an integer with (int)
    echo $number;                // will print 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` isn't a keyword in PHP.  So it's interpreting that as a variable name.  Which is then immediately following by another variable name (`$num_rows`), which is what the parser doesn't expect.

I think you mean this:

```
$num_rows = 0;
```

You don't need to declare a variable type.  The interpreter will discern the type when it needs to.